# SQL Query problem (2 different order by) in 1 table

Tags: sql

This is the original table:

[image]

I have 2 different query and I want to make 1 query for these:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM SAMPLE
WHERE ORDER_PRIORITY<40
ORDER BY FS_GENERATE_DATE IS NOT NULL, FS_GENERATE_DATE,ORDER_PRIORITY,CREATE_ID,CR_DATE,ORDER_QTY;
```

second:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM SAMPLE
WHERE ORDER_PRIORITY>=40
ORDER BY FS_GENERATE_DATE IS NOT NULL, FS_GENERATE_DATE,ORDER_PRIORITY,CREATE_ID,CR_DATE,ORDER_QTY;
```

I need the next result in only 1 query:

- if the order_priority<40 than the order will be the first according to the order by
- but if order_priority>=40 than these data will be after the lower priority (first conditional /op<40/).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Both order by clauses are identical.  Can you include sample data in your question?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to your `order by` clause:

```
case when ORDER_PRIORITY<40 then 0 else 1 end
```

The final query will be:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM SAMPLE
WHERE ORDER_PRIORITY>=40
ORDER BY 
case when ORDER_PRIORITY<40 then 0 else 1 end,
FS_GENERATE_DATE IS NOT NULL, FS_GENERATE_DATE,ORDER_PRIORITY,CREATE_ID,CR_DATE,ORDER_QTY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly using a database where booleans are allowed in the `ORDER BY`.  So, you can just use:

```
SELECT S.*
FROM SAMPLE S
ORDER BY (ORDER_PRIORITY < 40) DESC,
         FS_GENERATE_DATE IS NOT NULL, 
         FS_GENERATE_DATE,
         ORDER_PRIORITY,
         CREATE_ID, CR_DATE, ORDER_QTY;
```